# NLP and context based search using Elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, nlp

I have been using ES to handle regular text/keyword search, is there a way to use elastic search to handle context based search i.e when user have given a search text "articles between 10 august and 24 September" and such similar scenarios, ES should be able identify what user is asking and present results. I suppose we are supposed to involve ML to handle such scenarios, If any NLP or ML integrations need to be done where should i start to up the search experience.

**Any insight over this is much appreciated**

Comment: please refer the  [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26791412/elasticsearch-date-range) & [link2](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-daterange-aggregation.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is called semantic parsing. What you need to do is to map the sentence to a logical form. This is a challenging task, since the computer needs to understand your sentence. You may create your own Semantic Parser(e.g., [SEMPRE](https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/sempre/)) to do the translation, or use existing methods to do such translations ([translate human language to elastic search queries](https://www.inovex.de/blog/seqpolicynet-nlp-elasticsearch/)).